# linq query dynamically add where condition?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to filter records dynamically on user choice. The user may choose to show the debit amount greater than credit or credit amount greater than debit. Accordingly I want to put a condition similar to either `totDebit>totCredit or`TotCredit>totDebit`

```
Dim query = _
        From product In Bills.AsEnumerable() _
        Group product By accode = product.Field(Of String)("ACCODE"), _
        BILLNO = product.Field(Of String)("BILLNO") Into g = Group _
        Let totDebit = g.Sum(Function(proudct) proudct.Field(Of Decimal)("DEBIT")) _
        Let totCredit = g.Sum(Function(proudct) proudct.Field(Of Decimal)("CREDIT")) _
        Select New With _
         { _
            .ACCODE = accode, _
            .billno = BILLNO, _
            .TOTALDEBIT = totDebit, _
            .TOTALCREDIT = totCredit, _
            .BALNACE = totDebit - totCredit _
          }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

In the code you h ave shownm you've merely built a query; you haven't executed it yet.  And, at any point before you excute it, you may continue to build it:

```
 Dim query = _ 
    From product In Bills.AsEnumerable() _ 
    Group product By accode = product.Field(Of String)("ACCODE"), _
   ' etc as above....

   If onlyCredits Then
       query = query.Where(Function(proudct) product.TOTALCREDIT > product.TOTALDEBIT)
   Elseif onlyDebits Then
       query = query.Where(Function(proudct) product.TOTALCREDIT < product.TOTALDEBIT)
   Endif
```

Note, I'm a C# guy, so please forgive minor syntax errors....

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for Dynamic Query Library. Not included in Linq but availble for download from Scott Guthrie's blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

> Both the VB and C# DynamicQuery
>   samples include a source
>   implementation of a helper library
>   that allows you to express LINQ
>   queries using extension methods that
>   take string arguments instead of
>   type-safe language operators.

You can apply strings to filter the exection:

```
myData.DynamicWhere(string.Format("{0}.Contains(\"{1}\")", filter.field, filter.data.value));
```